# Frame layout height is reduced automatically to height of listview even though I set match_parent. How to fix this?

Tags: android, listview

I have ImageView, ListView and a ScrollView inside a FrameLayout. I want to show either list or the scrollview with textView depending on some conditions. The problem is that when there are few elements in the listView, the size of imageView is also reduced to the size of listView. I want ImageView to match_parent always.

Also I want imageView inside the same FrameLayout (container) as I set animation to container.

How to fix this?

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/arte"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <v.ui.dragListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/lyricsHolder"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lyrics"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:shadowDx="0.0"
            android:shadowDy="0.0"
            android:shadowRadius="8"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:typeface="serif"  />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/audio"
                android:text="Show Songs"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share screen shot of the output?

Comment: use fillviewport for your scrollview and set it to true.

Comment: I added the screenshot.

Comment: Hi Karan. Actually it didn't work. I forgot to remove another imageview that I set as fallback and I was thinking of that imageview as the one in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might find similar issue. The simple work-around that worked for me is adding an empty view tag with sufficiently large width/height as the case may be (in my case I use layout_height ="3000dp") as a sibling to the list view.

```
    <view android:layout_height = "3000dp"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:background = "@drawable/list_background/>
    <ListView ...../>
    <ImageView ..../>
```

After doing this it works as required.